# Character encodings and file_get_contents

Tags: php, html, utf-8, echo

I am studying PHP programming and I am testing some things.

I have been trying to download some HTML data with:

```
$this->html = file_get_contents($this->url);

$fh = fopen('txt\htm.txt', 'w') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($fh, $this->html);
        fclose($fh);
```

As soon as I run this script, it downloads the HTML from a page and saves it in a text file; up to here everything works fine.

Inside the HTML file, there is some data available that I want to extract and save in memory.

Example:

- "car"
- "banana"
- "tâllian" <-
- "dog"

The code that I use: (I am using XPath)

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML($this->html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

    $this->string1 = $this->GetName('//div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a/span',$xpath);
        $this->string2 = $this->GetName('//div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a/span',$xpath);
        $this->string3 = $this->GetName('//div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/a/span',$xpath);  
        $this->string4 = $this->GetName('//div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/a/span',$xpath);


    private function GetName($xquery,$xpath)
    {
        $result_rows = $xpath->query($xquery);
        foreach ($result_rows  as $result_object)
        {
            return substr($result_object->nodeValue, strpos($result_object->nodeValue, '>')+1,strlen($result_object->nodeValue) );
        }

}
```

And if I print:

```
echo 'tâllian<br>';
echo $this->string1.'<br>';
echo $this->string2.'<br>';
echo $this->string3.'<br>'; //tâllian
echo $this->string4.'<br>';
```

Result:

- tâllian     <-
- car
- banana
- tÃ¢llian     <-
- dog

So my problem is, why is the script returning "tÃ¢llian" instead "tâllian"?

I expect these problems are caused by my function `GetName`... What do you think?

**Interesting Facts**

- When I search the word "tâllian" in my text file ("txt\htm.txt"), I find it clean and clear.
- When I execute `echo 'tâllian';` it returns it clean and clear, because I have this header: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

---

**found solution:**

```
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8');
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
```

It need's to be converted before creating a new DOMDocument.

Comment: thanks for correcting my thread :), i approve it

Comment: Yeah, sorry I edited it 3 times. I made some typos too :/. Anyways, I've tried to answer your question.

Comment: What about encoding information within the HTML document itself?  Is there possibly meta tag that indicates the content is something other than UTF-8 (ISO 8859-1, for example)?  There are also some other people who have posted comments in the PHP documentation regarding ways to force UTF-8 processing. http://us1.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php#74777

Comment: good topic, it helped me aloot +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**found solution:**

```
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8');
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
```

It need's to be converted before creating a new DOMDocument.

Comment: i am the author, and i just shared the solution that i found, peace

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you use the `htmlentities();` method? Give the following code a try:

```
echo htmlentities($this->string3) . "<br />";
```

This is probably because those special characters, (in this one, the A with the roof ) aren't printed correctly when you print them as plain text. You should print them as HTML entity. The method used bellow does this automatically.

You can find more information about this method in the PHP page: [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/htmlentities)

Comment: compiled and tested, same result

Comment: Hmm, that's sad. But it's still great your tested the code though.

Comment: You should take a look at the answer @p-j-hinton gave you on your main question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301310/character-encodings-and-file-get-contents/20301436?noredirect=1#comment30292033_20301310

Comment: gonna check that :p, maybe i should leave notpad++ and get some good develop program and do some debug ^^

Comment: You should give PHPStorm a try, it's amazing with all of its features!

Comment: realy? gonna try that :o, installing :3